# products not showing in frontend magento

Tags: magento

about a week ago I had issues with the reindexing process so deleted all none required fields and it did not index for about a week however during that time the website failed to display any products. Now it is reindexing the products are enabled, instock, visible and selected to run on the main store but still nothing is displayed. When looking thorugh the catagories on the frontend it shows that there is products in the catalog (quantity) but shows no results. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem eventually by trial and error went into the database and copied the values from a known clean installation as the problem was in the catalog_eav table

Comment: While the problem may be solved in your case, a more specific answer for what the problem in the catalog_eav table was, and what change fixed it would be more helpful in this forum.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reindexing all again from magento admin panel then hope your problem will be solved.